# Laravel/Sentinel Call to undefined method on route

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios, sentinel

I am trying to build a notification system following this great tutorial:
https://jplhomer.org/2017/01/building-realtime-chat-app-laravel-5-4-vuejs/

Getting notifications from DB works fine but when I try to make a notification persist via post route I get the following error in my log:

I'm using Laravel 5.4, Sentinel, vue2 and axios

```
[2017-03-24 15:00:58] local.ERROR: BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::notification() in /Users/odp/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:2445
```

In my browser console all i get is:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 500
```

My get and post route is as follows:

```
// Notifications
Route::get('/notifications', function() {
    return App\Notification::with('user')->get();

});

Route::post('/notifications', function() {
    //$user = Auth::User(); //Original code from tutorial
    Sentinel::getUserRepository()->setModel('App\User');
    $user = Auth::getUser(); //Auth is now an alias for Sentinel

    $user->notification()->create([
    'notification' => request()->get('notification')
    ]);

    return ['status' => 'OK'];

});
```

**app/User.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Sentinel;

class User extends \Cartalyst\Sentinel\Users\EloquentUser
{
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'first_name', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function notifications()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Notification::class);
}
}
```

**app/Notification.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Sentinel; 

class Notification extends Model
{


    protected $fillable = [
        'notification',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

I don't know if it is relevant but this is from my app.js where I believe that the axios.post line creates the 500 error based on the failing route.

```
const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',

data: {

    notifications: []
},

methods: {

    addNotification(notification) {
        this.notifications.push(notification);

        axios.post('/notifications', notification).then(response => {

        })
    } 
},

created() {
    axios.get('/notifications').then(response => {
        //console.log(response);
        this.notifications = response.data;
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is that it's trying to call `notification` on a `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` object.

This leads me to believe that `Auth::getUser()` is actually returning a `Builder` object and not your actual User model.

I would try tacking on `->get()` to `$user = Auth::getUser()->get()`.

Comment: I ran through the steps for extending Sentinel one more time and saw that I missed a bit: https://github.com/cartalyst/sentinel/wiki/Extending-Sentinel#runtime

I have now added `Sentinel::getUserRepository()->setModel('App\User');`

to my route so that I can call Sentinel::getUser(); to get the user model.

But the error is the same. I have updated my question to reflect the change

Comment: try and run `dd(get_class($user));` to verify that the class ic orrect. If you are getting the same exact error, it means that `$user` is not an instance of your User model.

Comment: Also, when you do this: `$user->notification()` are you trying to create a Laravel Notification or an App\Notification? In your User model, you called the function `notifications` with an `S` at the end, but you are calling `notification` without the `S`.

Comment: OHH MY F'ING GOD. HOW DUMB AM I. yes, i am calling it without an S and it need an S. Can't believe I didn't see that, must have stared myself blind. Here I was focused on it had to be Sentinel giving me issues. Thanks for all the great feedback Brian.